# Equivalent of boxplot lwd parameter for bwplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice, bwplot

I want to have the box plotted with thicker lines. In `boxplot` function I simply put `lwd=2`, but in the lattice `bwplot` I can pull my hair out and haven't found a solution![image]
(with the box I mean the blue thing in the image above)

Sample code to work with:

```
require(lattice)
set.seed(123)
n <- 300
type <- sample(c("city", "river", "village"), n, replace = TRUE)
month <- sample(c("may", "june"), n, replace = TRUE)
x <- rnorm(n)
df <- data.frame(x, type, month)

bwplot(x ~ type|month, data = df, panel=function(...) {
    panel.abline(h=0, col="green")
    panel.bwplot(...)
})
```

Answer (score 7):

As John Paul pointed out, the line widths are controlled by the the `box.rectangle` and `box.umbrella` components of lattice's graphical parameter list. (For your future reference, typing `names(trellis.par.get())` is a fast way to scan the list of graphical attributes controlled by that list.)

Here's a slightly cleaner way to set those options for one or more particular figures:

```
thickBoxSettings <- list(box.rectangle=list(lwd=2), box.umbrella=list(lwd=2))

bwplot(x ~ type|month, data = df, 
       par.settings = thickBoxSettings,
       panel = function(...) {
           panel.abline(h=0, col="green")
           panel.bwplot(...)
       })
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh! OMG, why is lattice so contra-intuitive! I've spent almost two hours with this, just in the worst time pressure before my presentation at the conference! Only pitty that I was offline and couldn't ask here..

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is get the trellis settings for the box, and change those. Try

```
rect.settings<-trellis.par.get("box.rectangle") #gets all rectangle settings
rect.settings$lwd<-4  #sets width to 4, you can choose what you like
trellis.par.set("box.rectangle",rect.settings)
```

Put these above your bwplot call and it should do it.

The box rectangle settings also has color, fill etc.

Edit to add if you get `box.umbrella` you can edit it to change what the lines above and below the box look like.

Answer (score 3):

There is a further feature of lattice plots that needs mention. They are really objects, so methods exist for modifying their list representations;

```
myBW <- bwplot(x ~ type|month, data = df, panel=function(...) {
    panel.abline(h=0, col="green")
    panel.bwplot(...)
})
newBW <- update(myBW, par.settings=list(box.rectangle=list(lwd=4) ))
plot(newBW)   # need to print or plot a grid object
```

You can also use `trellis.focus` and apply further updating function to overlay new data or text.

Comment: Thanks DWin! OMG, why is lattice so contra-intuitive! I've spent almost two hours with this, just in the worst time pressure before my presentation at the conference! Only pitty that I was offline and couldn't ask here..

Comment: It's a completely different (object-oriented to a degree)  plotting paradigm. Designed for greater power, it does require adoption of a more list-oriented mind set.

Comment: Well, really, but it is so frustrating when the documentation is not very well-aranged and the stuff is not intuitive.. For example, `help.search("box.rectangle")` returns nothing. It would be perfect to have some documentation with just a picture of sample graph and names of all those parameters you need to set...

Comment: Yeah. I understand. I thought that buying Sarkar's book was money well spent. It's got good discussion and helpful charts of plotting parameter names. And once I got around to reading the `help('lattice-package', package="lattice")` page, I wondered why I had not done so before.